# Reactjs cannot reload Google Maps with new location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am trying to reload Google Maps with the new inputted location, but it is not reloading. The correct value of `lat` and `lng` is being passed back from the `SearchBar` component and the state is updating correctly. I am new to `react-google-maps`, so I am not sure if there is another way to update the map. I assumed that once I updated the state, Google Maps would re-rendered, but that is not the case.

1. index.js

   ```
   import React, { Component }from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import Map from './components/map';
   import SearchBar from './components/search_bar'
   import './index.css';

   class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = { center: {lat: 37.7547339, lng: -122.4744468 }}

     }

     locationSearch(term) {
       this.setState({center: JSON.stringify(term)});
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <div className="row">
             <div className="sidebar col-md-3">
               <SearchBar
                 onSearchTermChange={this.locationSearch.bind(this)}
                 googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
                 loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                 containerElement={<div style={{height: '400px'}} />} />
             </div>
             <div className="col-md-9">
               <Map 
                 center={this.state.center}
                 zoom={14}
                 containerElement={<div style={{height:'400px'}} />}
                 mapElement={<div style={{height:100 + '%'}} />} />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
   ```
2. search_bar.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { withScriptjs } from 'react-google-maps';
   import StandaloneSearchBox from "react-google-maps/lib/components/places/StandaloneSearchBox";
   import _ from 'lodash';
   /*global google*/
   class SearchBar extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.refs = {};
       this.state = { center: {lat:38.5382322, lng:-121.7639065 }};
     }

     onSearchBoxMounted(ref) {
       this.searchBox = ref;
     }
     bounds() {
       console.log("bounds");
     }
     onPlacesChanged() {
       const places = this.searchBox.getPlaces();
       const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

       places.forEach(place => {
         if (place.geometry.viewport) {
           bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport)
         } else {
           bounds.extend(place.geometry.location)
         }
       });

       const nextMarkers = places.map(place => ({
         position: place.geometry.location,
       }));

       const nextCenter = _.get(nextMarkers, '0.position', this.state.center);

       this.setState({
         center: nextCenter
       });

       this.props.onSearchTermChange(this.state.center);
     }

     render() {
       return(
         <StandaloneSearchBox
           ref={this.onSearchBoxMounted.bind(this)}
           bounds={this.bounds.bind(this)}
           onPlacesChanged={this.onPlacesChanged.bind(this)}>
           <input
             type="text"
             placeholder="Search for restrooms"
             style={{
               boxSizing: `border-box`,
               border: `1px solid transparent`,
               width: `240px`,
               height: `32px`,
               padding: `0 12px`,
               borderRadius: `3px`,
               boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
               fontSize: `14px`,
               outline: `none`,
               textOverflow: `ellipses`,
             }} />
         </StandaloneSearchBox>
       );
     }
   }

   export default withScriptjs(SearchBar);
   ```
3. map.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

   class Map extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
         map: null
       }
     }

     mapMoved() {
       console.log('mapMoved: '+ JSON.stringify(this.state.map.getCenter()));
     }

     mapLoaded(map) {
       if(this.state.map !== null) {
         return;
       }

       console.log("here: " + JSON.stringify(this.props.center));

       this.setState({
         map: map
       });
     }

     render() {
       const markers = this.props.markers || []
       console.log("reload");
       return (
           <GoogleMap
             ref={this.mapLoaded.bind(this)}
             onDragEnd={this.mapMoved.bind(this)}
             defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
             defaultCenter={this.props.center}>
             {markers.map((marker, index) => (
                 <Marker {...marker} />
               )
             )}
           </GoogleMap>
       );
     }
   }

   export default withGoogleMap(Map)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just based on quick look, I think you probably need to add componentWillReceiveProps() to the Map class and update the this.state.map using setState() when you have an updated value of lat and lng.